# Selenium, pop up form (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, forms, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to fill forms on certain webpages. I am having success with most 
pages however certain ones are giving me trouble.

Some pages have a format where the form is not initially visible on the page itself, instead you need to click a button which then opens a (what seems to be JavaScript) pop up within the page which then needs to be filled.

I have looked around and have seen examples which address how to fill forms which get created in a new pop up window and which get created in alert windows. However I can not seem to find any examples which can solve this particular case.

This is the code I have so far.

```
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)

     mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)    
     driver.get(url)

     driver.maximize_window()

     value = 'fill form'
     span_xpath = '//span[contains(text(), "' + value + '")]'
     span_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(span_xpath)
     mouse.move_to_element(span_element).click().perform()
     time.sleep(5)
```

Everything works till here, the fill form button gets clicked which opens the form in the browser page.

But when the following is execute an error always arises: "no such element: unable to locate element"

```
     n =driver.find_element_by_id('name')
     n.send_keys('john smith')
```

I have tried to locate the element by, name, id, xpath and so on but no matter what try, it can not locate any of the form elements.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Make sure pop element is not inside any frame/iframe??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur, Yes it is in a iframe. However its an iframe within an iframe. I can access the src of the first iframe using src = driver.find_element_by_id("iframe_id").get_attribute("src") . But the second iframe withiin that iframe does not have an id so i am not sure how to get its src

Comment: You need to switch first parent iframe before accessing child iframe

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I tried to do: driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_name("iframe_name")) and driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe')
but i still get the same element not found error

Comment: @SaurabhGaur This link describes the issue i am having: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=575 i can switch into the first iframe by doing driver.switch_to_frame(0) but once i switch into the nested iframe by doing  driver.switch_to_frame(0) again i get an error

Comment: @abcla, can you update the question with HTML showing iframe tags? because in the issue link that you shared, there is a discussion of closing frames and the status of the issue is **Fixed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First switch using `driver.switch_to_frame(0)  (parent iFrame)`
 then switch using `driver.switch_to_frame(1) (chiled iFrame)` 
and then `find the element`.

**Note:** instead of using `index` you can identify the frame using id, name, xpath etc. like any other Web Element and pass that element to switch_to_frame as an argument. This gives more consistency.